# Is there any detriment to fighting battles in Easy Mode?

Tags: mario-luigi-dream-team

When you die in a battle, you get the option to retry it in Easy Mode if you so wish.

It does make the battles a lot easier, but then I got to wondering - is there any sort of penalty in-game if I take the easy mode option? Or is Nintendo just being nice and helping me not want to throw my 3DS when battles are too hard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, all easy mode does is **heal you** (an effect which stays after the battle), makes **enemies weaker** and **you stronger**. The two latter effects wear off after the battle, but you stay healed.

There is **no penalty** for using easy mode, nothing later in the game will change for better or for worse.

Comment: it does show up at the end-game stats, under 'times KO'ed' or something